# How to ignore line breaks only below certain width

Tags: html, css

I have three paragraphs (or only one but with line breaks) like this:

```
line number one
line number two
line number three, longer.
```

Now, I want those three lines to behave just like one (so it can fluidly break where the screen forces it) when the width of the screen
reaches that of the longer line. So I end up with something like that, automatically:

```
line number one line  |
number two line number|
three, longer         |
```

(vertical lines represents screen width)

In other words: is there a way to have a paragraph to behave normally (breaking naturally) when the screen width forces it to, but to keep its line breaks when the screen width is bigger than those of the individual (and longest) lines?

Comment: Do you have a piece of example code? How are the paragraphs made up, is it one paragraph with breaks, or multiple paragraphs?

Comment: I don’t have the code for I don’t know how to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see any viable solution unless the markup within the paragraph can be changed. Or using some JS.

The best I can come up with right now is to set a `media` query which removes the `<br/>` tag at widths greater than the longest single line, and this width has to be fixed, unfortunately. In other words, if you wanted to use this across multiple paragraphs multiple media queries might be necessary.

The example below removes the `<br/>` tags at screen widths greater than 250px, which is about the width of the longest line. The result is the paragraph acts as a single line at widths greater than 250px and wraps at it's natural wrap points. At 250px and below it uses the `<br/>` tags to wrap.

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 250px) {
  p.break-250 > br {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  p.break-500 > br {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="break-250">
  line number one<br/>
  line number two<br/>
  line number three, longer.
</p>

<p class="break-500">
  line number one line number one<br/>
  line number two line number two<br/>
  line number three, longer line number three, longer.
</p>
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you.

Comment: If I have two or more blocks with different line width. How can I use the media query to address them separately?

Comment: You would have to add a class to target them individually. I'll update the example.

Comment: Thanks. But I still don’t know HOW to target different queries with classes. Can you write a small code, please?

Comment: Amazing. You are great! Thank you very much. This just saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

you can give max-width to parent div so your line naturally break

```css
 

div{  
  max-width:160px;
}
p{
  text-align:justify:
}
```

```html
<div>
<p>
line number one line  
number two line number
three, longer         
</p>
</div>
```